# Build error: Execution failed for task ':capacitor-android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor

I have a ionic capacitor project. After some package updates I am getting some build error in android studio.

This is the error:

```
> Task :capacitor-android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
Execution failed for task ':capacitor-android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> error: invalid source release: 17

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':capacitor-android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
    at 
etc
```

and then

```
Cause: error: invalid source release: 17
```

This is my configuration:

```
ext {
    minSdkVersion = 21
    compileSdkVersion = 33
    targetSdkVersion = 33
    androidxActivityVersion = '1.2.0'
    androidxAppCompatVersion = '1.2.0'
    androidxCoordinatorLayoutVersion = '1.1.0'
    androidxCoreVersion = '1.3.2'
    androidxFragmentVersion = '1.3.0'
    junitVersion = '4.13.1'
    androidxJunitVersion = '1.1.2'
    androidxEspressoCoreVersion = '3.3.0'
    cordovaAndroidVersion = '7.0.0'
}
```

```
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6a5g.png)

I am kindof lost on where to go from here and don't want to continue making changes and making thins worse

Thanks for any help

Update ---

This is my capacitor.build file:

```
android {
  compileOptions {
      sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
      targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}

apply from: "../capacitor-cordova-android-plugins/cordova.variables.gradle"
dependencies {
    implementation project(':capacitor-community-sqlite')
    implementation project(':capacitor-app')
    implementation project(':capacitor-camera')
    implementation project(':capacitor-filesystem')
    implementation project(':capacitor-haptics')
    implementation project(':capacitor-keyboard')
    implementation project(':capacitor-status-bar')
    implementation project(':capacitor-storage')
    implementation project(':robingenz-capacitor-app-update')
    implementation project(':robingenz-capacitor-file-picker')
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:27.+"
    implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing:4.0.0"
    implementation "com.revenuecat.purchases:purchases-hybrid-common:2.0.1"
    implementation "androidx.annotation:annotation:[1.2.0]"
}
```

Comment: My aim was to upgrade my min sdk version as per googles deadline and the billing version

Comment: Can you please check which Java version you are using in your IDE and what you have mentioned for project? It is different.

Comment: @Keshav I believe the ide is using Java 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When performing an Android build, the following error can be seen when Java 17 is expected in the build and the incorrect version of Java is being used:

```
Execution failed for task ':capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> error: invalid source release: 17
```

To correct this issue, you will next want to update gradle to version 8 or greater in the build.gradle file or alternatively you can set the OVERRIDE_JAVA_VERSION environment variable to 17 as described in this documentation.